# White noise lines across my render

Tags: rendering

I've been trying to render this one scene for a while now, and for whatever reason these white noisy lines appear every now and then. The appearance of these are seemingly random: every time I render the scene, it's not guaranteed that these will appear. A pattern I've noticed is that these lines only exclusively pop up when I enable the rendering of a giant cube that makes up the blue fog that you can see in the top of the attached images. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening or how to fix it? I'm rendering using cycles.

[image]

[image]